# PHP - preg_match regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to use `preg_match` to figure out if a url has certain pattern and right now its not working as I expected. Heres what I have so far:

```
if(! preg_match('^lease/([0-9]+)/?', $url)) {
    wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
}
```

Basically I want to see if the url pattern is as below(lease keyword followed by a number) and if not the page should be redirected to homepage. Im not good with regex so I need some help with this one. TIA.
`www.example.com/lease/324`

Comment: Use `if(! preg_match('~^.*/lease/([0-9]+)/?$~', $url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow any chars before the `/lease` with `.*?`,  an end of string anchor `$` and regex delimiters (I prefer `~` so as not to escape forward slashes):

```
if(! preg_match('~^.*/lease/([0-9]+)/?$~', $url)
```

Or you may omit `^.*?` part since `preg_match` allows partial matches

```
if(! preg_match('~/lease/([0-9]+)/?$~', $url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the capture group (parenthesis) unless you want to  know what the trailing numbers are. But looks like you just want to check if it contains `lease/{number}`

You can try this:

```
if (! preg_match("/lease\/[0-9]+/", $url)) {
    wp_redirect( home_url(), 301);
}
```

> contains lease, then a slash, then 1+ number

Comment: Usually being specific about types is good, but I'd say don't use `false === preg_match()`. "[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns `1` if the pattern matches given subject, `0` if it does not, or `FALSE` if an error occurred."

Comment: Also `[0-9]` could be `\d`.